# Tabs and Firefox button in title bar in Firefox for Mac OS X?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I have Firefox 5.0.1 in Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Are there ways to:

1. Make the Firefox Button appear on the top-left of the Firefox window (like the Windows and Linux versions)?
2. Let the tabs on top actually be in the title bar on the very top of the window, instead of still being in their own row/bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an open bug for this [Bug 625989 - Support tabs in title bar on Mac OS X](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625989) on Bugzilla so I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I see, I guess we'll have to wait! Thanks for the link.